# MySQL Update totals table with count and cursor without locking values table

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, database-performance

I'm interested in being able to incrementally update a row in a `Totals` table with counts or sums from a `Values` table without blocking inserts into `Values`.

The idea is to collect all the values with id's greater than the total checkpoint, then update the total count and checkpoint. This will create a snapshot to `Totals`. Here are the tables:

```
Table: Totals
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Totals` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `values_checkpoint` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Table: Values
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `total_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `total_id_id` (`total_id`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

A query combining the snapshot and values could look like this:

```
SELECT t.count + count(v.total_id),max(v.id) 
FROM `Totals` t
JOIN `Values` v ON v.total_id = t.id AND v.id > t.values_checkpoint
WHERE t.id = 1;
```

The problem comes with updating the `Totals` row.

Translating this directly to an update will not working because MySQL won't allow the aggregate methods in update.

Joining on a subquery will not work because it can't be correlated and I need a WHERE clause for `id > t.values_checkpoint`.

Setting `t.count` and `t.values_checkpoint` separately will not work because it can block inserts to `Values` in `REPEATABLE READ`, and they will not be consistent in `READ COMMITTED`

The only way I can figure out how to make this work is to start a transaction and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` the total row to get the values_checkpoint which can be used in the Join subquery. This is not ideal because I'd need to leave a lock hanging with a transaction open.

Is there someway to update both `t.count` and `t.values_checkpoint` with a single update statement and a single SELECT on `Values`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going from where you "left off" all the way to the end, constrain it to go no more than, say, 1000 rows.  This will keep the interference to a smaller amount of time.  (Use less that 1000 if needed.)  It might also be good to precompute (outside the transaction) a 'good' stopping point.

```
SELECT @stop := LEAST(t.values_checkpoint + 1000, MAX(v.id))
    FROM ...
```

Then proceed to do the query; presumably IODKU will suffice (and always do the update side):

```
INSERT INTO Totals (id, count, values_checkpoint)
    SELECT t.count + count(v.total_id), max(v.id) 
        FROM `Totals` t
        JOIN `Values` v ON v.total_id = t.id
               AND v.id > t.values_checkpoint
               AND v.id <= @stop
        WHERE t.id = 1
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        count = VALUES(count),
        values_checkpoint = VALUES(values_checkpoint);
```

Then do the update frequently enough so that you rarely get behind by 1000.